# Disabling a jQuery script in HTML for a specific window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js, responsiveness

I know this is probably a very basic issue, but I'm building a website with the help of the fullPage.js script ( https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js ), but with little jQuery/Javascript knowledge.

What I want to do is disable the script for window width of 800px and less, but have it enabled for higher. Alternatively, I'd want to set a certain variable to false inside the script with the same condition.

This is how the script looks like (I removed some settings to make it shorter):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                responsiveWidth: 800,
                continuousVertical: true
            });
        });
</script>
```

This was my attempt at making it work simply, but it doesn't appear to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ( $(window).width() > 800) {
   $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                responsiveWidth: 800,
                continuousVertical: true
            });
        });
}
</script>
```

Comment: You'll likely want the `if ($(window).width()..` within the `$(document).ready` function. Perhaps even in a `$(window).resize(function () { });` event handler.

Comment: Are you linking to the jquery library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fullPage.js responsive options, such as `responsiveWidth` or `responsiveHeight`.

[Example online](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/responsive.html)

```
 $('#fullpage').fullpage({
     responsiveWidth: 800,
     continuousVertical: true
 });
```

As detailed [in the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js):

> **responsiveWidth:** (default 0) A normal scroll (autoScrolling:false) will be used under the defined width in pixels. A class fp-responsive is added to the body tag in case the user wants to use it for his own responsive CSS. For example, if set to 900, whenever the browser's width is less than 900 the plugin will scroll like a normal site.
>
> **responsiveHeight:** (default 0) A normal scroll (autoScrolling:false) will be used under the defined height in pixels. A class fp-responsive is added to the body tag in case the user wants to use it for his own responsive CSS. For example, if set to 900, whenever the browser's height is less than 900 the plugin will scroll like a normal site.

Additionally you can make use of the class `fp-auto-height-responsive` to prevent fullPage.js to restrict the size of your sections to a 100% height. Read about it [in the docs too](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#responsive-auto-height-sections).

## Update

As detailed in the answers, now he wants to know how to disable `verticalCentered` on mobile devices.
It is as easy as making use of the responsive option detailed above (that will also disable autoscrolling) and its [state class](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs) to overwrite the `.fp-tableCell` class applied to the sections when using `verticalCentered:true`.

```
.fp-responsive .fp-tableCell {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: The issue I have is that I'm trying to switch `verticalCentered` to `false` when at mobile layout. Vertical centering makes responsive design really difficult, and the only thing that this option does is disable the scrolling effect.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about `verticalCentered` in your question... But in any case, I've updated my answer. Check it out.

Comment: @Simplici7y you should be accepting this answer as valid on the right tick at the left. This way other people landing in this quesiton will know what's the right answer.

Comment: Thank you, quite a beginner when it comes to this. Will keep it in mind for the future as well.

Answer (score 0):

The condition is switched around. `$(window).width()`**<**`800` Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ( $(window).width() < 800) {
   $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                responsiveWidth: 800,
                continuousVertical: true
            });
        });
}
</script>
```

Comment: No need for a condition.... the responsive option is in fact the condition itself. Read my answer for more info.

Comment: I tried it both ways, unfortunately, doing this completely disables the script for any window size.